# Unable to return all the results at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, return

I've written a script in python to fetch some links from a webpage. There are two functions within my script. The first function collect links to the local businesses from a webpage and the second function traverses those links and collect urls to the various events.

When I try with the script [found here](https://pastebin.com/8eaN1Nm1), I get desired results.

***How can I return all the results complying the below design?***

The following script ***return*** the results of individual links whereas I wish to ***return*** all the result at once keeping the design as it is (logic may vary).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

linklist = []

def collect_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    items = [urljoin(url,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".business-listings-category-list .field-content a[hreflang]")]
    return items

def fetch_info(ilink):
    res = requests.get(ilink)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".business-teaser-title a[title]"):
        linklist.append(urljoin(url,item.get("href")))
    return linklist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.parentmap.com/atlas"
    for itemlink in collect_links(url):
        print(fetch_info(itemlink))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I removed the global `linklist` as it is returned from the function anyway, and keeping global creates overlapping results. Next I added a function to "assemble" the links the way you wanted. I used a set to prevent duplicate links.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def collect_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    items = [urljoin(url,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".business-listings-category-list .field-content a[hreflang]")]
    return items

def fetch_info(ilink):
    linklist = []
    res = requests.get(ilink)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".business-teaser-title a[title]"):
        linklist.append(urljoin(url,item.get("href")))
    return linklist

def fetch_all_links(url):
    links = set()
    for itemlink in collect_links(url):
        links.update(fetch_info(itemlink))
    return list(links)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.parentmap.com/atlas"
    print(fetch_all_links(url))
```

Comment: So, I sould not use global variable like the way I tried in my script @SimonF, right?

Comment: If you use a global list all links are appended to it, so each call to fetch_info will start with a non empty list, which is then returned

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are getting results one after another is you are calling fetchinfo in a loop which calls function, again and again, resulting in printing data one after another rather than using a loop in fetchinfo function.Try code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

linklist = []

def collect_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    items = [urljoin(url,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".business-listings-category-list .field-content a[hreflang]")]
    return items

def fetch_info(url):
    for itemlink in collect_links(url):
       res = requests.get(ilink)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        for item in soup.select(".business-teaser-title a[title]"):
            linklist.append(urljoin(url,item.get("href")))
    return linklist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.parentmap.com/atlas"
    for itemlink in collect_links(url):
        print(fetch_info(itemlink))
```